# Is there a safe way to cache and resize remote images with PHP?

Tags: php, image, security

I am working on an RSS reader using SimplePie.

I want to pull in RSS feeds and display articles with thumbnails. I am using RSS Enclosures and will later parse RSS <items> for <img>'s.

Is there a safe way to download these remote images to my server so I can cache them and resize them?

I have some ideas about how it can be done with cURL for instance, but I'm interested in security. I know I can restrict by file extension and I could probably look at the MIME type, but I just want to know if this is at all feasible/safe. If so, what steps should be taken to ensure there are no vulnerabilities.

Comment: What specific security concerns are you worried about?

Comment: Probably XSS or just executing any code from a malicious RSS feed that tricks my application into thinking its scripts are images. I know that SimplePie is pretty good about avoiding XSS, but it is a security risk to just download an arbitrary remote file to a public location on my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resize Images With [gd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [imagemagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

or you can do it in this way Check out the following [Link](http://joedesigns.com/v22/?page=scripts_widgets&id=67)

Comment: +1: amending the cotnent using such a tool should remove any malicious content - just don't store the raw image inside your document root.

Comment: Alright so there is no risk in opening a remote file with GD or imagemagick, so long as I don't store the original? Also, I'll take a look at that link. I'm not as concerned with actually writing this as I am with the security since I have a good understanding of security but I'm no expert.

Answer (score 0):

Posible security issues:

- Execution of remote script. Somehow you download a php script instead of an image and server executes it on later call to this image.

Solution: in any web server you can configure upload directory so, that no script can be executed there. And don't forget to add proper extetion to images (better to select from list, do not trust mime-types).

- XSS on client reading RSS. You download an image. But it ocures to be a javascript.

Solution: make sure you insert link to this imgae in `<img src"...">` tag. Script would not be executed from img tag. Moreover, resizing image through GD or Imagic will certanly spoil any js inside, if there was one.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I think I've got the second part covered. Also, it is possible to execute a script from the src attribute of an image, so I'm not sure that that is 100% safe by itself ([link](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html)). Of course the tip about using GD or imagemagick sounds useful.